# How can I query to get the rows according to the certain column's value in oracle?

Tags: oracle, dynamic, row

Table A is:

```
--------------
C1      C2
--------------
A       3
B       2
--------------

select * from
(
    select 'A' as C1, 3 as C2 from dual
    union all 
    select 'B' as C1, 2 as C2 from dual
)
```

I want to get the following result view with one query statement:

```
--------------
C1    N1
--------------
A      1
A      2
A      3
B      1
B      2
--------------
```

I need to generate rows as many as C2 value

Is this possible?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

We can handle this via the use of a calendar/sequence table.  Consider:

```
WITH nums AS (
    SELECT 1 AS val FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 FROM dual
)

SELECT
    a.C1,
    n.val AS N1
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN nums n
    ON n.val <= a.C2
ORDER BY
    a.C1,
    n.val;
```

[image: screen capture of demo below]

### Demo

Note that in practice, you might use a dedicated table containing a sequence of numbers to cover all possible values in your table.  Or, you might use an Oracle sequence.

Comment: Thank you so much, Tim. Really Thank you. Good solution

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively:

```
SQL> with test as
  2  (select 'A' as C1, 3 as C2 from dual
  3   union all
  4   select 'B' as C1, 2 as C2 from dual
  5  )
  6  select c1, column_value n1
  7  from test cross join table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
  8                                           connect by level <= c2
  9                                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 10  order by c1, column_value;

C         N1
- ----------
A          1
A          2
A          3
B          1
B          2

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Littlefoot. Thank you. I could know the new things.